MAUI Add different Android Plattforms for different Devices
i have a couple of different android devices each with its own hardware drivers for their built in Barcodereaders and RFID Readers.
What is the best way to support the different android devices in one MAUI Project?
Edit:
There are some different things.
For Example Zebra devices use an EMDK for Device Configuration and Barcode Reading plus a DLL for RFID Reader
Nordic Device have just a DLL for Barcode reading.
I cant create an apk with all the DLLs and Packages, it wont run, because for example if this is no zebra device, the app cant connect to the Device Interface for emdk and it fails
So I need a way to create and compile subplatforms for android that produce own apks

Did you mean you want to launch the Barcodereaders and RFID Readers app from your app on different device?

I mean you can natively query which readers are available can't you?

probably the solution would be to create anothe maui project in the solution with only the Android platform and use filelinks for all the same files. or can I use a shared dllproject in a maui solution?

If I understand it correctly you should be able to add from View backend code specific camera by if statements where you would define the Android version. It would look like this:
#if ANDROID21_0_OR_GREATER this.MyLayout.Add(new ZxingCamera()); #elif ANDROID20_0_OR_GREATER this.MyLayout.Add(new ZebraCamera());
